# How to add a show/hide comment link not working with underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

UPDATE - To help explain this I have created a fiddle which can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/Dano007/b11xarpp/5/

Overview.

I'd like to add a read more/collapse link to my comments, the visibility of comments will be restricted if over a certain size and the user will click "read more" to see them.

I found this example JS code here which seems perfect.  http://jsfiddle.net/xn6Sp/9/

Problem.

I'm using a underscore.js .each wrapper to display my comments on the page, like so.

```
_.each(Badges, function (item) {
  var wrapper = $('<div></div>');

  wrapper.append('<div id="comments"  class="item"></div>' + ' Reason: ' + item.comment + '</div>' + '<br>');

  $('#container').append(wrapper);

});
```

However, using this seems to create the following issues.
1 - The read more link is not appended correctly
2 - It looks like the JS is reading the div contents as being empty and therefore not working.

Bounty is for:
1 - Making the read more/collpase link work correctly with the code shown in this jfiddle.
 http://jsfiddle.net/Dano007/kgybcuqq/1/

Comment: Your example only has two objects right? How can we produce more results? any idea?

Comment: @RahulPatil I have added further objects, if you re run the fiddle you should see at least 5. Does that help?

Comment: check the answer. I tried to explain the things as much as I can. Comment if you need any further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

`myBadgeQuery.find` is async method, success function invokes only after the data is retrieved from server (parse.com in this case).

So ideally, the collapse logic is supposed to be executed after you append the data inside DOM.

I created function called `collapseIt` and wrapped all the collapse logic inside it and called it inside `success` of `myBadgeQuery.find`..

```
myBadgeQuery.find({
  success: function (Badgeresults) {

    var Badges = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < Badgeresults.length; i++) {
      Badges.push({
        comment: Badgeresults[i].get('Comment'),


      });

    }

    _.each(Badges, function (item) {
        console.log("Got the data");
      var wrapper = $('<div></div>');

      wrapper.append('<div id="comments"  class="item"></div>' + ' Reason: ' + item.comment + '</div>' + '<br>');

      $('#container').append(wrapper);


    });                            

    //Invoke collapse code after you append the data. This is async function so you have to wait till data is appended.
    collapseIt();


  },
  error: function (error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

Collapse code :

```
   //////////////////Hide/show comments on code//////////////
var collapseIt = function(){
     var collapsedSize = '20px';
   $('.item').each(function() {
    console.log("inside each");       
    var h = this.scrollHeight;

    console.log(h);
    var div = $(this);
    if (h > 30) {
      div.css('height', collapsedSize);
      div.after('<a id="more" class="item" href="#">Read more</a><br/>');
      var link = div.next();
      link.click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        if (link.text() != 'Collapse') {
          link.text('Collapse');
          div.animate({
            'height': h
          });

        } else {
          div.animate({
            'height': collapsedSize
          });
          link.text('Read more');
        }

      });
    }

  });   
};
```

Updated Fiddle.. Should work for you. http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/kgybcuqq/3/

Fiddle with individual collapsible links : http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/kgybcuqq/4/

Comment: @Ruhul Paril, thats on the right lines, my only comment is that it is treating the 5 db comments as one object not 5. THese comments may appear in different places and are not connected. Is it possible to change it so there are 5 read more/collapse options, one for each comment? Many thanks

Comment: @Dano007 http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/kgybcuqq/4/ This fiddle should help you.. If you need, I can explain :-)

Comment: it looks perfect thank you! will award the bounty as soon as it will let me! Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function () {

    var Badges = {
        "comment" : ["stuff", "stuff", "stuff", "stuff"
                    , "stuff", "stuff the end"]
    };
    $.each(Badges.comment, function (key, value) {

      $("#container").append('<br /><span id=comment-'+key+'>' 
                 + ' Reason: ' + value + '</span>');

    });

    var collapsedSize = '50px';
    $('.item').each(function () {
        var h = this.scrollHeight;
        var div = $(".item");
        if (h > 30) {
            div.css('height', collapsedSize);

            div.after('<a id="more" href="#"'
                      + 'style="display:block;'
                      + 'position:relative;margin-top:4px;">'
                      + 'Read more'
                      + '</a><br/>');
            $("#container *:gt(3)").filter(function (i, el) {
                return $(el).offset().top > $("#more").offset().top
            }).hide();
            var link = div.next();
            link.click(function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                link.text(function (i, o) {
                    return o === "Read more" ? "Collapse" : "Read more";
                });
                if (link.text() === 'Collapse') {
                    div.animate({
                        'height': h
                    });
                    $(".item *").show();
                } else {
                    div.animate({
                        'height': collapsedSize,
                    });
                    $(".item *:gt(3)").hide();
                }
            });
        }
    });

})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/kka3n0h3/

Comment: This seems like a good answer, but I cannot get it working with my code, which actually populates the comments from a Db. Not sure how far you want to go helping look at this?

Comment: @Dano007 If possible, can describe details of effects /issues of piece at post within production piece ? ; fork / adjust jsfiddle to illustrate issues ? ; post / describe how comments section is populated from db , other `html` , or portions of piece which may not be currently included at OP ?